# What do I call someone I hire to do my personal work for me?

Tags: single-word-requests

Currently I’m living in Place A, but I need a representative at Place B who will go there and perform work on my behalf. He will update me on the progress in Place B.

What is that person called?

Comment: What kind of work for you? Many small trivial tasks? Act as your stand-in for important decisions as though it were you? Somewhere in between? 'Personal assistant' for the more trivial. Did a thesaurus give you any ideas?

Comment: @Mitch is right: you really cannot choose a word without knowing what kind of work they would be doing. *Aide, associate, deputy, drudge, employee, flunky, gofer, hireling, lackey*, and *subordinate* all come to mind.

Answer (score 5):

*Representative* itself might be appropriate. A possible alternative is *agent*.

Comment: +1 Agent is best. An agent acts on your behalf, a representative represents you. Someone doing a job which doesn't interact with other people, isn't representing you but is still your agent.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the word [*proxy*, which is defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proxy)

> 1. A person authorized to act for another; an agent or substitute.

Answer (score 1):

Agent is the best and most literal word, but if you want to use some very contemporary american slang, used by upperclass people who are internet savvy and have money to spare, they might hire a 'task rabbit', so named after the website used to hire them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get ridiculously formal and over the top, you could use **charge d'affaires** (sorry, can't figure out how to enter accents in this text editor).  It implies that you yourself are a person of some importance but are unavailable at the moment, and this other agent of yours is authorized to act on your behalf in your absence.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charg%C3%A9%20d%27affaires